# Hide a column that I am calculating

Tags: mysql, sql

In my query, I am finding payment_method, removing all rows that do not have  its value as 'cod', but I want to remove this column from the output. How can I do so?

```
SELECT
    max( CASE WHEN um.meta_key = 'hrid' THEN um.meta_value END ) AS HRID,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS order_total,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_payment_method' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS payment_method
FROM wp_posts p
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items oi ON p.ID = oi.order_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_users u ON u.ID = pm.meta_value AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta um ON um.user_id = u.ID
WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' and post_status = 'wc-completed'    
GROUP BY p.ID
HAVING payment_method = 'cod'


Result right now
HRID    order_total    payment_method
x       y              z

Expected result
HRID    order_total
x       y
```

Comment: If you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Throw the 4th line out of your code. At the end of MAX you have `AS payment_method' which is the name of the variable you want to remove. Throw out the entire line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the condition to the `having` clause:

```
SELECT max( CASE WHEN um.meta_key = 'hrid' THEN um.meta_value END ) AS HRID,
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS order_total
FROM wp_posts p
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items oi ON p.ID = oi.order_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_users u ON u.ID = pm.meta_value AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta um ON um.user_id = u.ID
WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' and post_status = 'wc-completed'    
GROUP BY p.ID
HAVING  max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_payment_method' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) = 'cod'
```